# Spring boot validation question to valid the list of the object which belongs the parts of request

Tags: java, validation

I have a model class like following:

```
@Data
public class Customer {
    String customerName;  
    List<Address> addresses;
    // the rest of the field

}
```

For the `Address` class

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Address {
    private String address1;
    private String address2;
    private String addressType;
    private int addressTypeId;
    private String city;
    private String houseNumber;
    private String state;
    private String streetName;
    private String zipCode;
    private String zipPlus4;
}
```

In my controller I need to validate the `Customer` Object, the valid customer object need to have two addresses, one is the physical and one is billing. And also for each address, it also need to validate the `houseNumber`, `streetName`, `state`, `city`, `zipCode`, those fields cannot be empty..

Like if user provide the physical address but missing one of the fields I want to return the message said `"Physical address is missing either one of fields: houseNumber, streetName, city, state, zipCode"`

What should be the correct way to write the validation?

Answer (score 0):

I would use Bean Validation annotations on both classes.
For `Customer` use the `@Min` and `@NotNull` in the `addresses` field.
For `Address` use either `@NotBlank` or `@NotEmpty`.

Spring has an integration for bean validation so it should work out-of-the-box. You can also customize the message response in the annotations.

However I would suggest using separate fields for billing and physical address in case that there are always two of them. Otherwise you'll have to iterate and find out which address is billing and which one is physical every time.